# Request.Url.Host returns the wrong host?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

I have a single `Umbraco 7` instance that has `2 root nodes`.  One node points to `stage.sctflash.com` and the other node points to `stage.bullydog.com`.  When I navigate to `http://stage.bullydog.com/Products/accessories/podmount`, the `Request.Url.Host` is `stage.bullydog.com`.  Now, if I open up another tab and go to `http://stage.sctflash.com/Products/accessories/podmount`, the `Request.Url.Host` might be `stage.sctflash.com`, but sometimes, it just changes to `stage.sctflash.com`.

The one strange thing I noticed is that if I view the accessories node in `Umbraco`, I noticed the parent of it is `stage.bullydog.com` no matter if I am on `stage.sctflash.com` or `stage.bullydog.com`

I am using `Request.Url.Host` to determine as a query parameter to a database.  I am basically getting the brand like this:

```
if(Request.Url.Host == "stage.sctflash.com")
return "sct";
else
return bullydog";
```

So essentially if `Request.Url.Host` is intermittently wrong, I get the wrong query parameter.

To see this in action, if you go to `http://stage.sctflash.com/Products/accessories/podmount`, you will see an SCT logo, then go to `http://stage.bullydog.com/Products/accessories/podmount` and you will see a Bully Dog logo.  These logos are driven by `Request.Url.Host`.  If you refresh `http://stage.sctflash.com/Products/accessories/podmount`, you most likely will see the `Bully Dog` logo now because `Request.Url.Host` is now `stage.bullydog.com` instead of `stage.sctflash.com`

This is the action method that is called when I go to this page: `http://stage.sctflash.com/Products/accessories/podmount`

```
  public ActionResult GetAccessoriesByType(RenderModel model, string id)
    {
        string brand = Common.GetProductBrand(Request.Url.Host);

        var productSearchResultsModel = new ProductSearchResultsModel
        {
            Accessories = _accessoryRepository.GetAccessoriesByType(id, brand)
        };

        return View("~/Views/accessories.cshtml", productSearchResultsModel);
    }
```

Comment: `Request.Url` ain't broken, it's your code that is. There's not enough information in your question to determine the actual issue. Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information about this one page displaying this behavior.

Comment: @CodeCaster - Hi, I updated the post.  Let me know if that helps.  Currently, this is baffling me.

Comment: Most likely your code is not thread safe. The first thread retrieves the correct value, but another thread (from the other domain) somehow overwrites the value before it makes it to the UI. But since you haven't posted your code, I can't be more specific than that.

Comment: @NightOwl888 - Hi, I added to code where i get the brand.  The weird thing is that it only happens on that particular page I posted, every other page gets the brand fine.

Comment: @xaisoft - Ok, the fact that your method is static is inline with my theory. But the problem is not in that function. You need to post more of the code - the code that calls this function all the way to the code that calls the top of the stack (most likely a controller action). If you are storing the result of this function anywhere inside a static variable (or a statically referenced class that contains a non-static variable), that is where your problem lies.

Comment: @NightOwl888 - I posted the action method that gets called when I access `http://stage.sctflash.com/Products/accessories/podmount`.  I am assumming at this point `Request.Url.Host` is from the previous request?  Is that correct?

Comment: Is this line the culprit: `string brand = Common.GetProductBrand(Request.Url.Host);`.   If `Common.GetProductBrand` is static, does that mean it is shared among requests to the action method?